# columns independently spanning over multiple pages in reportlab's pdfgen

Tags: python, reportlab, multiple-columns

I am trying to create a pdf with two columns spanning over multiple pages where each column gets populated independently of the other. Pdfgen though seems to fill up all available space pagewise and not documentwise. I have tried with code similar to this:

```
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(myFile, pagesize = A4, leftMargin = 0, rightMargin = 0, topMargin = 0, showBoundary=1)

Elements=[]
p1 = Paragraph("I am column 1! " * 300, styles['Normal'])
p2 = Paragraph("I am column 2! " * 800, styles['Normal'])

frame1 = Frame(1.45*cm, doc.bottomMargin + 1*cm, doc.width/2-1.45*2*cm, doc.height-7*cm, id='col1')
frame2 = Frame(doc.width/2 + 1.45*cm, doc.bottomMargin + 1*cm, doc.width/2-1.45*2*cm, doc.height-7*cm, id='col2')

doc.addPageTemplates([
    PageTemplate(id = 'TwoCol', frames = [frame1,frame2], onPage = self.headerAndFooter),
])

Elements.append(NextPageTemplate('TwoCol'))
Elements.append(KeepTogether(p1))
Elements.append(FrameBreak())   
Elements.append(KeepTogether(p2))

doc.build(Elements)
```

Am I missing something essential, or is it just not possible within the limits of pdfgen?

Comment: If the columns are populated independently, doesn't a table (without lines) work better?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The main reason why I choose not to use tables is not the semantics, it's rather that my columns very well might get larger than one page, which renders a LayoutError. There might of course be a way to split table cells if they don't fit in one frame, but I'm too unexperienced in using pdfgen. If you have a solution for the LayoutError I would be very glad if you shared it with me!

Comment: The old way is to count lines (or points if lines are different height) and put a doc.append(PageBreak()) before it's too late. It has worked for me.

Comment: you're fundamentally limited here because you want to do something that goes against the way reportlab is designed to work. if you want a pretty solution, what you will probably have to do is write a custom flowable class, similar to paragraph, that somehow knows what frame it should display in and prevents itself from displaying in the wrong frame so that it will "wait" until the next page.

Comment: this is the limitation of reportlab, luckily i have a fixed rows per page and I need to count rows and place a pagebreak after that.