# Wrong breaking columns in ReportLab RML

Tags: python, pdf-generation, reportlab, rml

i have set page template like this(split page by two columns)

```
    <pageTemplate id="secondary">
        <frame id="columnLeft" x1="15mm" y1="15mm" width="90mm" height="267mm"/>
        <frame id="columnRight" x1="114mm" y1="15mm" width="90mm" height="267mm"/>
    </pageTemplate>
```

Problem is that when content is breaking on the second page it first goes to the left column, even if it was in the right column.

I just need that content from left column on page break was moved to the left column on next page and content from right column to the right.

Comment: It's not straightforward due to limitations of Reportlab. Please have a look at this question and comments - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867744/columns-independently-spanning-over-multiple-pages-in-reportlabs-pdfgen

Comment: Ok. Maybe you know where i can find documentation about extending RML lib to support custom tags with custom flowables?

Comment: You may need to dive into source code and search for some blogs/tutorials.
1. http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/03/10/reportlab-how-to-create-custom-flowables/
2. https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab
3. https://github.com/zopefoundation/z3c.rml

I've only used RML for creating custom report cards for students. For complex multi column formatting I've used Latex in past.

Comment: Another resource will be official documentation - http://www.reportlab.com/apis/reportlab/2.4/index.html